# Access a Google Spreadsheet from an App without using its link - Android Studio (Java)

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I am developing a mobile application that the user must choose a spreadsheet that already exists in their google account, so that the information is shown in the app.

I've already managed to get the user to log into the application and authorise Google Drive access from his account.

Now I'm trying to find a way to be able to see and access the files that are in Google Drive, in which case what interests me is the spreadsheet that is in the user's account, without using the spreadsheet link.

All Scopes are authorized, we use SHA1 and OAuth as well.

[image: Here the Image when someone open the App]

[image: Here the Image after the user log in into the app, and authorize the Google Drive Access, and go to Settings]

[image: Here is some example of a window that may be open to the user select which file he wants the app to read]

I need some help to solve this problem, or another idea to do that without using the spreadsheet link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Files:list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list). In python it would be

```
files = service.files().list(q="'root' in parents and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'").execute()['files']
```

Comment: This answer is fine but take into account that the query parameter is including `'root' in parents` which will not include files in subfolders. Also you can look more into this types of queries [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-search-terms)

Comment: Im aware, you could just remove `'root' in parents` and get all files. Although it seems like a bad idea to just list all the files without the folder stucture in an app

Comment: Thanks guys, ill try to transform this code in java language. If any of you know what it would look like in java, please let me know!